# How to detect one source of funnel plugin has ended in gstreamer pipeline?

Tags: gstreamer, h.264

I am using gstreamer to build a pipeline with two source. One is a file source (`filesrc`), the other is `appsrc`. When the filesrc got EOS, the pipeline do not quit. `appsrc` still get `need-data` signal and will never stop itself. It seems `funnel` plugin will wait for all sources to end before sending EOS to pipeline. Is there a way to get notified when filesrc got end of file?

gst-launch command looks like this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 funnel name=f \
appsrc name=appsrc-h264-sei do-timestamp=true block=true is-live=true ! video/x-h264, stream-format=byte-stream, alignment=au ! queue ! f. \
filesrc input.h264 ! queue ! f. \
f. ! queue ! h264parse ! video/x-h264, stream-format=byte-stream, alignment=au ! mp4mux ! filesink location=file.mp4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install a `GstPadProbe` at the the funnel input pad and check for the EOS event on the callback.

Comment: Sounds solid. Could you provide more instructions? I have experience to create probe to process buffer, but I do not know how to check EOS event in probe callback.

Comment: I found an enum GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_EVENT_BOTH, is this the event to listen?

Comment: I think GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_EVENT_DOWNSTREAM should be enough. Upstream could be an QOS event but you are not interested in that.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!